# EF Core 6 not able to complete the migration with unable to create object of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using the latest preview 6 of ef core in a test application to learn the braking changes however. I have a couple of things wrong

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Concierge.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
public class ConciergeDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ConciergeDBContext(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<ConciergeDBContext>
    options)
      : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

For some reason I have to qualify my model builder with Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions for if I dont i get ambiguity with my DB Set command but that is not all when I compile it I am getting.

> Unable to create an object of type 'ConciergeDBContext'. For the
> different patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
> supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Now I have my web api project select as start up project and its configured as such

```
services.AddDbContext<ConciergeDBContext>
(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), 
ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

So why on earth am i getting the above error.

I am using the command

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -p  Concierge.Dal
```

When I get the above also outputdir also doesnt appear to be a valid argument in the ef 6 world.

My project structure.

[image]

My Concerige.Dal nugets

```
<ItemGroup>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21355.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1">
 <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
 <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
 </PackageReference>
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-preview.6.21352.1">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

My Context lives within the dal project.

[image]

Reason I am using IdentityDbContext is to create custom fields onto my user table so maybe that is part of the issue but this used to work in ef 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`

> You can also tell the tools how to create your DbContext by
> implementing the
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.IDesignTimeDbContextFactory
> interface: If a class implementing this interface is found in either
> the same project as the derived DbContext or in the application's
> startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the
> DbContext and use the design-time factory instead.

Place the implementation under `ConciergeDBContext` class. as a result, while migration it will be discovered and invoked.

```
public class ConciergeDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ConciergeDBContext(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions<ConciergeDBContext>
    options)
      : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Building> Buildings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
public class ConciergeDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ConciergeDBContext>
{
    public ConciergeDBContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConciergeDBContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connection_string);

        return new ConciergeDBContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why must I include Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. for my DBContext options I didnt used to have to thakns for detailed answer

Comment: @csharpdudeni77, my understanding of such situation is that , actually you are working on a lib class which is not contained a run-able application or have not program entry point so its run-time env is not defined or be defined then you need explicitly tell the lib what to do when it's built.

Comment: I have all my ef libarys in the dal class libary so it is aware

Comment: @csharpdudeni77 when I see your solution, dal is a lib class as well.